# Incremental backup in mariaDB mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am using 5.5.41-MariaDB and ENGINE is MyISAM on CentOS 7. Please help me for Incremental backup command of mariaDB mysql on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

You might check out Percona's Xtrabackup solution and see if it will work with MariaDB as all seem to be drop-in replacements.

See: https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/xtrabackup_bin/incremental_backups.html

Some articles imply this would work in MariaDB. I only use Percona so cannot confirm unfortunately: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/backup-restore-and-import-xtrabackup/

Comment: I see you are using MyISAM and Percona is known for InnoDB so may have to check if it will work for MyISAM too.  The 2nd link does say it's designed for InnoDB but will work with other storage engines so should work for you.